# what is the fastest way to call a php file from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sockets

What is the best way to call a php file from vb.net? ideally i would need something that can be put inside a function and call with a couple of parameters to pass onto the url string. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [System.Net.HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
    Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(New System.Uri("http://contoso.com/query.php?param1=val1&param2=val2"))

    request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Http.Get

    Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()

    ' process response here

    response.Close()
```

Comment: Thats what i had initially, was slow though, i will give it another go! Thanks.

Comment: @RaymieClarkson Well, it depends what exactly means slow for you. Acording to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336009/how-to-get-a-fast-net-http-request a request should be built in less then 100ms (or even less than 50ms at average) as soon as JIT doesn't impact anymore.

Comment: 1-3 seconds per call, i need to investigate it a bit more, my browser will load a full html/php page on the same server faster than it will make a call to an empty page from vb.net!